# Why are words ending in -icious evil

Tags: etymology

Words ending in -icious seem to be almost entirely negative.

- vicious
- malicious
- pernicious
- avaricious
- suspicious

I can think of "delicious" which doesn't follow the negative connotation pattern.

The -cious ending is pretty sibilant, which I know is generally associated with evil.

But I wonder if these words all have some common origin? Why are they so disproportionately negative?

Comment: Auspicious, judicious, meritricious.

Comment: Delicious, propitious. Five and five.

Comment: "Evil"?  I think that's going a bit far. Also, *suspicious* seems a bit out of place in that list.

Comment: Sorted transpicuously: *appendicious, judicious,
prejudicious, injudicious, deficious, maleficious, beneficious,
veneficious, officious, inofficious, pontificious, artificious, inficious,
licious, malicious, immalicious, babelicious, delicious, felicious, 
infelicious, cilicious, silicious, multiplicious, bootylicious,
vermicious, pernicious, paroicious, extispicious, circumspicious,
conspicious, auspicious, inauspicious, suspicious, avaricious, lubricious,
capricious, matricious, pulveratricious, meretricious, obstetricious,
politicious, recepticious, vicious, convicious, servicious.*

Comment: @Xanne Shall one assume that by *meritricious* you meant something more meritorious than merely *meretricious*? :)

Comment: @tchrist It seems on closer reading that meretricious (so-spelled) actually belongs in the “negative” category, having to do, oddly enough, with prostitution.  *Meritricious* was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is pretty much a coincidence.

The Latin suffix *-osus* approximately means "full of" (or *-ful*). There are a lot of *-ful* words in English that have negative meanings, such as *painful, sinful, scornful, disdainful, mournful*. But the negativity mainly comes from the meaning of the root, not the suffix.

In the case of *vicious, malicious, pernicious, avaricious, suspicious,* the consonants before *-ious* are not actually all the same in the Latin sources. They are from

- *vitium*
- *malitia*
- *pernicies*
- *avaritia*
- *suspicio*/*suspitio*

The *-it-* in *avaritia* and *malitia* occurs in a common abstract noun ending in Latin: *-itia.* The other words just happen to be built on stems containing *-it-* or *-ic-*. Latin *t* and *c* both came to be pronounced the same way in this context in the varieties of Latin and French that English got the *-ious* adjectives from, but they were originally different consonants (although *suspicio* already showed variability in spelling in Latin).

As the comments mentioned, there are other positive *-icious* words than *delicious* such as *auspicious, judicious.*